# Group_by latitude and longitude in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that has two columns: Latitude and Longitude.

I have certain (latitude, longitude) pairs that are repeated for example:

35.650417 | 65.135421
35.650417 | 65.456462

How could merge the repeated pairs into one row and have a new column stating how many times each pair was repeated?

The previous example would become:

35.650417 | 65.135421 | 2

Comment: aren't they two distinct geo-codes with the longitude being different?

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['latitude','longitude']).size()
```

Comment: lesson learnt. didn't realize such qsns shouldn't be answered in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

```
df.groupby(['latitude','longitude'], as_index = False).count()
```